# A good book for learning paper and thin-layer chromatography

Tags: chromatography, books

What book would you recommend for learning paper and thin-layer chromatography? I don't have access to fancy equipment (just to these two basic techniques that are relatively cheap), so it would be nice if the book focused on them in addition to being easy to understand etc. It does not matter if advanced techniques are discussed in a chapter or two but if the book is solely about them, it would not offer me much.

Comment: I would be interested in this as well, in the form of a complete guide. Maybe, an introductory book on biochemistry techniques could contain what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think an entire book on TLC/paper chromatography would be quite overkill and your best bet is on a more general practical organic chemistry book. I can recommend [The Organic Chem Lab Survival Manual: A Student's Guide to Techniques](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118083393) by Zubrick if you are only interested in technique or need a introductory text. Else [Vogel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582462363) is of course *the* book for practical organic chemistry. TLC is covered in detail.

I'm not so sure about paper chromatography, I don't believe it is often used in the lab (at least I have never worked with it). TLC is much more common.